# Class inheritance issue when using tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, tkinter

I am receiving an exception which implies a problem with my inheritance structure, but cannot figure out the problem.

```
import tkinter as tk
class Game(tk.Tk):
class Period(tk.Frame, Game):
class PeriodSummary(tk.Frame,Period):
```

This gives the excpetion:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter_test.py", line 4, in <module>
    class PeriodSummary(tk.Frame,Period):
TypeError: Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases Frame, Period
```

So I want to have `Period` to inherit attributes from `Game`, and `PeriodSummary` to inherit attributes from `Period`. Why is this not possible?

Comment: It looks like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of how inheritance works. Why does `PeriodSummary` need to inherit from these other classes? Why are s a `Period` also a `Game` instead of being part of a game? What do you think that accomplishes?

Comment: A `Game` has many `Period`s. After each Period is played, I would like there to be a `PeriodSummary` frame come up. `Period` inherits from `Game` because  it needs attributes from it, but has also differet attributes.

Comment: Read what you just wrote: a game _has_ many periods. Each period is not _also_ a game, which is what your inheritance is saying. One `Game` object should have several `Period`  objects as attributes. You don't want to use inheritance just because you need to share data, that's not what  inheritance is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't inherit from both `Frame` and `Tk`. Those are very different things, and inheriting from both simply won't work as you expect. Plus, a tknter app should always only have a single instance of `Tk`.

You also shouldn't inherit from `Frame` and also from some other class that inherits from `Frame`.

Comment: But why does it not work? Is there something I can adjust?

Comment: @splinter: it doesn't work because it isn't designed to work. This is simply the wrong way to use tkinter. An object can't be both a frame and a root window at the same time.